# change CORS port dynamically

Tags: django, django-cors-headers

I want to give front access to my endpoints, but their ports range from 3000 to 3005 how can i set that dynamically or set those all

```
 CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3001',
    'http://localhost:3000',
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`: A list of origins (comma separated values) a cross-domain request can be executed from.

If the special `*` value is present in the list, all origins will be allowed. An origin may contain a wildcard (*) to replace 0 or more characters (i.e.: http://*.domain.com). Usage of wildcards implies a small performance penalty.

```
Only one wildcard can be used per origin.
```

Example: `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://*.domain.com,http://*.domain2.com`

Comment: so can i do something like this `http://localhost:*` , I am a little unfamiliar with regex and what about this `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
r"^https://\w+\.domain\.com$",
]`

Comment: hey @AtifShafi, I'm not familiar with Django, but looking at the documentation, if you want to expose your app to everyone, you can set CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True and remove the CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS. It can be dangerous, by the way, if you give me some examples, I can try to create a regex for you.

Comment: @AtifShafi `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES` works only for versions after `Django 3.2`
But how do I enable it for version `2.2`

Comment: @rickster you should post this as query